# ListView EditItemLayout cancel action

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have great troubles with trying to "cancel" edit of items in `ListView`.
In `InsertItemTemplate` in `ListView` I'm using button which triggers this command in code behind:

```
ListView.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None;
```

However,is `EditItemTemplate` missing this property?

can anyone get me at least direction to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cancel editing you can use this codes:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCanceling(object sender, ListViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: majidgeek thank you, thank you verry much. :) I've been working on this for hours.