# ListView cancel editItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm having trouble returning to listview and cancelling the edit of items using ASP and C#.

I already have the same answer as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608792/listview-edititemlayout-cancel-action)
 but I'm still getting the error message of `Cancel can only be called from the currently-edited record or an insert item.`

Here is the offending code - any pointers on what is causing this would be very useful:

I also have a layout, selected template, and insert which are all identical.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDatasource1"
                    EnableViewState="true" DataKeyNames="EndUserId" AllowPaging="True"
                    OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" OnItemCanceling="ListView1_ItemCanceling">

    <EditItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="tbId" Text='<%#Eval("EndUserId") %>' Visible="false" />
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbEmail" Text='<%#Eval("Email") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbRole" Text='<%#Eval("Role") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

c# backend controlling

```
    protected void ListView1_ItemCanceling(object sender, ListViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
        ListView1.DataBind();      
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
            ListView1.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.LastItem;

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

            }
        }
```

**added backend**

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Update")
            {
                Label tbId = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("tbId");
                TextBox tbEmail = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbEmail");
                TextBox tbPass = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbPass");

                string updateCommand =
                    "UPDATE [EndUser_tbl] SET [Email]='" +
                    tbEmail.Text + "', [Password]='" + tbPass.Text +
                    "'WHERE EndUserId=" + Convert.ToInt32(tbId.Text) + ";";
                sqlDatasource1.UpdateCommand = updateCommand;
            }
            if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                Label id = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("tbId");
                string deleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [EndUser_tbl] " +
                        "WHERE EndUserId=" + Convert.ToInt32(id.Text);
                sqlDatasource1.DeleteCommand = deleteCommand;
            }
            if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
            {
                TextBox tbEmail = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbEmail");
                TextBox tbPass = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbPass");


                string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO [EndUser_tbl] " +
                        "([Email],[Password],[ContractRef],[Role])" +
                        "VALUES ('" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbPass.Text + 
                            "','" + tbPass.Text + "');";

                sqlDatasource1.InsertCommand = insertCommand;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you do in ListView1_ItemCommand??

Comment: Similar to the below for insert, edit and delete, tried with cancel but it was giving the same error.

if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                Label id = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("tbId");
                string deleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [User_tbl] " +
                        "WHERE UserId=" + Convert.ToInt32(id.Text);
                sqlDatasource1.DeleteCommand = deleteCommand;
            }

Comment: Could you put the whole ListView1_ItemCommand by edit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Page_load like this way：

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
             ListView1.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.LastItem;
        }
    }
```

And try it again.

Comment: Knew it would be something simple! Thanks for your help!